# How can I write a conditional coloring command that distinguishes variables within sectioning commands vs those within the body text?

Tags: sectioning, color, conditionals

## Question

Is it possible to write a conditional statement for commands that change them based on where they appear in the document?

### Example Situation

When command appears in the body, it should be

- bold and black in color.

When it appears in a heading/title (sectioning commands: `\section \subsection, \paragraph` etc.),

- make it bold and red.

In the following code, I use the command `\keyword` in the heading `\section` and in the body. I would like to appearance of the text to change based on where it is found. This means I would need access to two conditions:

1. for any type of sectioning command
2. for the body

## Sample Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Product \keyword{rabunza}}
You can find the information about \keyword{rabunza} on our website.
\end{document}
```

---

## Question Extension

[I have extended this question here to include `titlesec/titletoc/tocloft` compatibility.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225097/13552)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hook in the commands that produce the section titles, the easiest way is with `sectsty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\allsectionsfont{\colorkeywordstrue}
\newif\ifcolorkeywords

\DeclareRobustCommand{\keyword}[1]{%
  \textbf{\ifcolorkeywords\color{red}\fi #1}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Product \keyword{rabunza}}
You can find the information about \keyword{rabunza} on our website.
\end{document}
```

[image]

How does `sectsty` work? It adds hooks to the sectioning commands (it's not important to know how). These hooks are called

- `\allsectionsfont`, which affects all titles
- `\<level>font` which affects the specified level (`\sectionfont`, `\subsectionfont` and so on).

The names are due to the fact that the package was thought for easily changing the formatting of titles, but the hooks are simply executed at the right moment and can contain anything.

In this case, we add the declaration `\colorkeywordstrue`, that makes the conditional `\ifcolorkeywords` return true. By default it returns false; the hooks are executed in a group, so the meaning of `\ifcolorkeywords` will be restored as soon as the section title has been typeset.

Comment: I like having this alternate approach. It does wonders for my understanding of `latex`! Unlike Werner's answer, I do not understand your code yet. This is likely because I have not read the documentation for `sectsty`. Your answer does seem more "conditional"-based.

Comment: Your code seems to break titlesec, which is essential for my work. :) This was not in my minimal working example, but I wish I had put it in there now.

Comment: @macmadness86 How can I know it, since you don't even mention `titlesec` in your question? It's obvious that `sectsty` and `titlesec` conflict with each other.

Comment: It was certainly not obvious to me that including titlesec would be an issue until after I tested it. Afterall, it is called a "minimal" working example. Of course I realize that this was not a criterion for my original question, hence my previous comment.

Answer (score 6):

[`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) provides hooks into sectional units where you can change the font. We could sneek in a redefinition of `\keyword` as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,sectsty}

\newcommand{\sectionkeyword}{% Update \keyword in sectional unit
  \renewcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries ##1}}}
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\sectionfont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sectionkeyword}

\begin{document}
\section{Product \keyword{rabunza}}
You can find the information about \keyword{rabunza} on our website.
\end{document}
```

This can be extended to other sectional units in a very similar way. See the [`sectsty` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty/sectsty.pdf) for information on the other units' font-macros.

Comment: Is this answer compatible with `\titlesec` and custom sectioning commands? I could figure this out on my own. Maybe you know off-hand?

Comment: @macmadness86: No (although not tested). [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) uses its own macro setup for constructing sectional titles; completely different from that of [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty).