# How can I write a conditional coloring command that distinguishes variables within titles vs within the body text with titlesec/titletoc/tocloft?

Tags: sectioning, color, conditionals, titlesec, tocloft

## Question

Is it possible to write a conditional statement for commands that change them based on where they appear in the document, yet is fully compatible with the `titlesec` package and the `tocloft` package? [This is an extension of this original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224971/13552). The original question does not address the issue of `titlesec/titletoc/tocloft`, three packages that I need.

### Example Situation

When command appears in the body, it should be

- bold and black in color.

When it appears in a heading/title (sectioning commands: `\section \subsection, \paragraph` etc.),

- make it bold and red.

In the following code, I use the command `\keyword` in the heading `\section` and in the body. I would like to appearance of the text to change based on where it is found. This means I would need access to two conditions:

1. for any type of sectioning command (including those of titlesec)
2. for the body

## Sample Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc,tocloft}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\color{blue}\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\color{blue}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlecontents{section}[0mm]{\color{gray}\large\bfseries\thecontentslabel\quad}{}{}{}
\titlecontents{subsection}[2em]{\color{gray}}{\thecontentslabel\quad}{}{\titlerule*[10pt]{.}\contentspage}

\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{Product \keyword{rabunza}}
You can find the information about \keyword{rabunza} on our website.
\end{document}
```

Comment: egreg's answer works here too. Try `\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\color{blue}\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\colorkeywordstrue}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Harish Kumar says in the comment, [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224973/27635) works here, as well.

It suffices to turn to true the "colorkeywords" conditional inside your commands:

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\colorkeywordstrue\color{blue}\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\colorkeywordstrue\color{blue}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlecontents{section}[0mm]{\colorkeywordstrue\color{gray}\large\bfseries\thecontentslabel\quad}{}{}{}
\titlecontents{subsection}[2em]{\colorkeywordstrue\color{gray}}{\thecontentslabel\quad}{}{\titlerule*[10pt]{.}\contentspage}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc,tocloft}

\newif\ifcolorkeywords

\DeclareRobustCommand{\keyword}[1]{%
  \textbf{\ifcolorkeywords\color{red}\fi #1}%
}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\colorkeywordstrue\color{blue}\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\colorkeywordstrue\color{blue}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlecontents{section}[0mm]{\colorkeywordstrue\color{gray}\large\bfseries\thecontentslabel\quad}{}{}{}
\titlecontents{subsection}[2em]{\colorkeywordstrue\color{gray}}{\thecontentslabel\quad}{}{\titlerule*[10pt]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Product \keyword{rabunza}}
You can find the information about \keyword{rabunza} on our website.
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. I attempt to implement it in a larger document and my headings turn black just like in the other question. The keywords are red as they should be.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to remove the `sectsty` package, which was conflicting with `titlesec`