# How to prevent page break between two section headings with color formatting using titlesec?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, titlesec

## Description

This question is based on almost the the following question,
[How to prevent page break between two section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101565/how-to-prevent-page-break-between-two-section-headings). The answer given [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101643/13552) explains that the problem is with `\color`, which adds a `whatsit` while in vertical mode (vertically breakable).

The solution is to use `\textcolor`, which takes two parameters (color and text), and does not insert a `whatsit`. This is described as follows:

> which works because the last instruction in the sixth argument to \@startsection reads the section title (with the number) as a braced group, which can then be interpreted by \textcolor as its second argument.

The answer uses the standard section definitions. I would like to have a solution that uses a`titlesec` definition (with the `explicit` parameter enabled).

## Details not really part of problem but possibly important

I use logic for coloring certain tags within the titles from [How can I write a conditional coloring command that distinguishes variables within sectioning commands vs those within the body text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224971/how-can-i-write-a-conditional-coloring-command-that-distinguishes-variables-with):

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\colorspecialstagstrue\color{black}\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\thesection\quad#1}

\newif\ifcolorspecials
\DeclareRobustCommand{\specialtag}[1]{%
    \textbf{\textit{{\ifcolorspecials\color{orange}\fi #1}}}%
}%
```

## Example

*Note that the title number (label) `\thesection` should normally be in parameter 4, because parameter 5 allows you to easily input the horizontal separation between the label and the title text. I have advanced code in the real document (using TikZ) that makes it necessary to include it in parameter 6.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Title/Heading Formatting
% SECTION
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\color{black}\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\thesection\quad#1} % \thesection "incorrectly" in 6th param due to tikz formatting in actual document.
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{40pt}{5ex plus .2ex}
% SUBSECTION
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\color{red}\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection\quad}{0pt}{#1} % Color in 3rd param adds whatsit messing up nobreak mechanism between titles/headings
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
% SUBSUBSECTION
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\color{red}\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection\quad}{0pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


\begin{document}
\section{Family}
\lipsum[1-4]
More junk to take up space and hopefully force a page break between Genus and Species such that this example illustrates the problem.
\subsection{Genus}
\subsubsection{Species}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as with your specification for `\section`, you can move all the printing commands into the final argument.  This then allows you to color them with `\textcolor`.  In your example you then get

[image: Sample output]

on page two, rather a page break between the section commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Title/Heading Formatting
% SECTION
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\textcolor{black}{\thesection\quad#1}}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{40pt}{5ex plus .2ex}
% SUBSECTION
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\textcolor{red}{\thesubsection\quad#1}} 
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
% SUBSUBSECTION
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\textcolor{red}{\thesubsubsection\quad #1}}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


\begin{document}
\section{Family}
\lipsum[1-4]
More junk to take up space and hopefully force a page break between Genus and Species such that this example illustrates the problem.
\subsection{Genus}
\subsubsection{Species}
\end{document}
```

Probably you will need to do something similar in your tagging command:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\specialtag}[1]{%
    \textbf{\textit{{\ifcolorspecials\textcolor{orange}{#1}\else #1\fi}}}%
}%
```

Comment: My problem with the tagging command is that my entire title text variable is passed into a TikZ node (I keep getting errors). I know that I did not provide a working example for this, because I wanted to keep my example to a minimum. I will post some notes later in my question about this. You did answer the question, however.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to cope with formatting of section titles is to use a macro with one argument in the last argument to `\titleformat`. Color specifications should only go in this auxiliary macro.

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Title/Heading Formatting
% SECTION
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\Huge\bfseries\global\let\thisnumber\relax}
  {\gdef\thisnumber{\thesection\quad}}
  {0pt}
  {\dosection}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{40pt}{5ex plus .2ex}
% SUBSECTION
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
  {\Large\bfseries\global\let\thisnumber\relax}
  {\gdef\thisnumber{\thesubsection\quad}}
  {0pt}
  {\dosubsection}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
% SUBSUBSECTION
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
  {\normalsize\bfseries\global\let\thisnumber\relax}
  {\gdef\thisnumber{\thesubsubsection\quad}}
  {0pt}
  {\dosubsubsection}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\newcommand{\dosection}[1]{%
  \textcolor{black}{\thisnumber#1}%
}
\newcommand{\dosubsection}[1]{%
  \textcolor{red}{\thisnumber#1}%
}
\newcommand{\dosubsubsection}[1]{%
  \textcolor{red}{\thisnumber#1}%
}


\begin{document}
\section{Family}
\lipsum[1-4]

More junk to take up space and hopefully force a page break between Genus and Species such 
that this example illustrates the problem.

\subsection{Genus}
\subsubsection{Species}

\section*{Test}
\subsection*{Test}
\subsubsection*{Test}
\end{document}
```

I also show that unnumbered sections work as expected. In the definition of `\dosection` and the similar macros you can test whether `\thisnumber` is `\relax` or not, instead of just using `\thisnumber` with

```
\ifx\thisnumber\relax
  <code for a starred section>
\else
  <code for a numbered section using \thisnumber>
\fi
```

[image]