# How to force linebreak at toc?

Tags: table-of-contents

Generated TOC has a weird alignment. How to fix?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \section{Загальні зауваження до конфігурації комплексів XXXXX01RACK01,  XXXXX01RACK02 и YYYYY01RACK01}
 \blindtext
 \section{General comments on the configuration for the following systems XXXXX01RACK01,  XXXXX01RACK02 и YYYYY01RACK01}
 \blindtext
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manually force a line break in ToC you can use the optional argument to `\section` and include a `\protect\\` or `\protect\linebreak` there:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \section{foo}
 \section[Загальні зауваження до конфігурації комплексів\protect\\
 XXXXX01RACK01,  XXXXX01RACK02 и\protect\\ YYYYY01RACK01]{Загальні зауваження до конфігурації комплексів XXXXX01RACK01,  XXXXX01RACK02 и YYYYY01RACK01}
 \blindtext
 \section[General comments on the configuration for the following systems
 XXXXX01RACK01,  XXXXX01RACK02 и\protect\\YYYYY01RACK01]{General comments on the configuration for the following systems
 XXXXX01RACK01,  XXXXX01RACK02 и YYYYY01RACK01}
 \blindtext
\end{document}
```

But perhaps using this optional argument to use a shorter version of the `\section` heading which breaks naturally might be better.

[image]

Comment: But this also breaks the section title in the header of the page. It produces a large space instead of breaking the line in the header. Is there any solution which will keep the header intact

Comment: @Damitr instead of using `\\ ` you could use a macro like `\mylinebreakonlyintoc` and use `\newcommand*\mylinebreakonlyintoc{\space}` in the preamble. Then put `\begingroup\renewcommand*\mylinebreakonlyintoc{\\}` before and `\endgroup` after `\tableofcontents`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using the optional argument, you can also write a custom command to print a linebreak when you are not in a section header (cf. [How to determine if a macro is used inside the argument of a sectioning command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388657/how-to-determine-if-a-macro-is-used-inside-the-argument-of-a-sectioning-command)). This can be done by patching the `\section` command to switch a toggle and testing for the toggle in the custom command. The advantage is that you don't have to repeat the section titles twice, but if you want to use this on other levels (e.g., subsection titles) then you need to patch these as well.

MWE (no Ukrainian, sorry):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{insidesection}
\togglefalse{insidesection}
\patchcmd{\section}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\toggletrue{insidesection}}{}{}
\newcommand{\mybreak}{\iftoggle{insidesection}{\ }{\\}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{My section\mybreak with linebreak}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. 'Optional argument' seems easier to use for me :)